# How to get "Tesla P100" in Google Colab in programmaticly way?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Maybe you heard that Google Colab has P100 GPU, It is way more faster than other all GPUs except V100 (V100 is avaliable in only Colab Pro.). As Its powerful, its pretty rare in Colab Free (P100). I didnt get "Tesla P100" in Colab before. So I tried to code a program that **Factory Resets Runtime** until getting "Tesla P100-PCIE..." text in nvidia-smi **(If you create a cell which contains !nvidia-smi in code, You'll get your GPU's model)** . I tried to do with Selenium but It failed cause of "This browser may not be secure" error. Then I tried to do with Javascript (Google DevConsole) but It failed cause of an error that I dont know what does it mean. So Im here.

**[Q] How to get "Tesla P100" in Google Colab in programmaticly way?**